# Unicode Conversions

Tags: c++, strings, unicode

This is the implementation I've been using to convert between unicode strings for a while. I basically pieced it together from information off the internet, including finding a work around for the bug in the Microsoft Visual C++ standard libraries of certain versions. I've really only been using the UTF-8 and UTF-32 conversions, so the UTF-16 stuff isn't as well tested. The last bit is an optional portion for reading files with BOMs, which I think are great for text files.

The header file is just a list of declarations for the conversions. The source has conversions done via codecvt, excluding 32->16 and 16->32 which are implemented via UTF-8 conversion. Stream wrappers would be a good addition, and memory usage could be improved, but it gets the job done. Let me know what you think.

**utf.hpp**

```
#ifndef UTF_HPP
#define UTF_HPP

#include <string>

std::string to_utf8(const std::u16string &s);
std::string to_utf8(const std::u32string &s);
std::u16string to_utf16(const std::string &s);
std::u16string to_utf16(const std::u32string &s);
std::u32string to_utf32(const std::string &s);
std::u32string to_utf32(const std::u16string &s);
std::u32string read_with_bom(std::istream & src);

#endif //UTF_HPP
```

**utf.cpp**

```
#include "utf.hpp"

#include <codecvt>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#if _MSC_VER == 1900 || _MSC_VER == 1910

std::string to_utf8(const std::u16string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<int16_t>, int16_t> convert;
    auto p = reinterpret_cast<const int16_t *>(s.data());
    return convert.to_bytes(p, p + s.size());
}

std::string to_utf8(const std::u32string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<int32_t>, int32_t> convert;
    auto p = reinterpret_cast<const int32_t *>(s.data());
    return convert.to_bytes(p, p + s.size());
}

std::u16string to_utf16(const std::string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<int16_t>, int16_t> convert;
    auto asInt = convert.from_bytes(s);
    return std::u16string(reinterpret_cast<char16_t const *>(asInt.data()), asInt.length());
}

std::u32string to_utf32(const std::string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<int32_t>, int32_t> convert;
    auto asInt = convert.from_bytes(s);
    return std::u32string(reinterpret_cast<char32_t const *>(asInt.data()), asInt.length());
}

#else

std::string to_utf8(const std::u16string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char16_t>, char16_t> conv;
    return conv.to_bytes(s);
}

std::string to_utf8(const std::u32string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> conv;
    return conv.to_bytes(s);
}

std::u16string to_utf16(const std::string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char16_t>, char16_t> convert;
    return convert.from_bytes(s);
}

std::u32string to_utf32(const std::string &s)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> conv;
    return conv.from_bytes(s);
}

#endif

std::u16string to_utf16(const std::u32string &s)
{
    return to_utf16(to_utf8(s));
}

std::u32string to_utf32(const std::u16string &s) {
    return to_utf32(to_utf8(s));
}

std::u32string read_with_bom(std::istream & src)
{

    enum encoding {
        encoding_utf32be = 0,
        encoding_utf32le,
        encoding_utf16be,
        encoding_utf16le,
        encoding_utf8,
        encoding_ascii,
    };

    std::vector<std::string> boms = {
        std::string("\x00\x00\xFE\xFF", 4),
        std::string("\xFF\xFE\x00\x00", 4),
        std::string("\xFE\xFF", 2),
        std::string("\xFF\xFE", 2),
        std::string("\xEF\xBB\xBF", 3)
    };

    std::string buffer((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(src)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    encoding enc = encoding_ascii;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < boms.size(); ++i) {
        std::string testBom = boms[i];
        if (buffer.compare(0, testBom.length(), testBom) == 0) {
            enc = encoding(i);
            buffer = buffer.substr(testBom.length());
            break;
        }
    }

    switch (enc) {
    case encoding_utf32be:
    {
        if (buffer.length() % 4 != 0) {
            throw std::logic_error("size in bytes must be a multiple of 4");
        }
        int count = buffer.length() / 4;
        std::u32string temp = std::u32string(count, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            temp[i] = static_cast<char32_t>(buffer[i * 4 + 3] << 0 | buffer[i * 4 + 2] << 8 | buffer[i * 4 + 1] << 16 | buffer[i * 4 + 0] << 24);
        }
        return temp;
    }
    case encoding_utf32le:
    {
        if (buffer.length() % 4 != 0) {
            throw std::logic_error("size in bytes must be a multiple of 4");
        }
        int count = buffer.length() / 4;
        std::u32string temp = std::u32string(count, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            temp[i] = static_cast<char32_t>(buffer[i * 4 + 0] << 0 | buffer[i * 4 + 1] << 8 | buffer[i * 4 + 2] << 16 | buffer[i * 4 + 3] << 24);
        }
        return temp;
    }
    case encoding_utf16be:
    {
        if (buffer.length() % 2 != 0) {
            throw std::logic_error("size in bytes must be a multiple of 2");
        }
        int count = buffer.length() / 2;
        std::u16string temp = std::u16string(count, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            temp[i] = static_cast<char16_t>(buffer[i * 2 + 1] << 0 | buffer[i * 2 + 0] << 8);
        }
        return to_utf32(temp);
    }
    case encoding_utf16le:
    {
        if (buffer.length() % 2 != 0) {
            throw std::logic_error("size in bytes must be a multiple of 2");
        }
        int count = buffer.length() / 2;
        std::u16string temp = std::u16string(count, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            temp[i] = static_cast<char16_t>(buffer[i * 2 + 0] << 0 | buffer[i * 2 + 1] << 8);
        }
        return to_utf32(temp);
    }
    default:
        return to_utf32(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should checkout [std::codecvt](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) by embuing the stream correctly you should be able to read any type of input stream and get the required output without any need for conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I suggest moving from constant references to `std::basic_string<T>` to values of type [`std::basic_string_view<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view). That gives you greater flexibility in providing the input without any cost.

Also, I suggest adding pass-through-versions inline for generic code.

---

Now, that was all about the interface. Let's look at the implementation.

1. The first enum-constant always has value zero, unless manually overridden.
2. Using a `std::vector` to store the array of boms is severe overkill and blatantly inefficient. A simple constant raw array can fill the need.
3. You don't gain anything by using anything more complicated than raw string literals, with their length either stored as the first element or as part of a `std::pair`. In fact, changing to that makes it all compile-time-constant, with the advantage to size and speed that entails.
4. The extra-parentheses around the first argument of the initialization of `buffer` are curious...
5. You know you can safely treat `buffer.data()` as a pointer to an array of `char16_t` or `char32_t`, as long as the `buffer.size()` is right?

   That's due to `std::string` using `std::allocator` which uses `operator new()` which guarantees that any returned buffer is properly aligned for storage of any object.

   And because we changed the other functions to accept `std::basic_string_view<T>`s, we don't even have to allocate yet another copy for things for re-coding.